# Build cropped PDF image from LaTeX

Tags: preview, crop, standalone

I have created an image with `pgfplots` in a separate file and want to add the PDF that is built from that as an image in my report. The problem is that the image PDF created is a complete A4 format.

How can I just build a LaTeX file with minimal paper size? What `documentclass` do I need?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        title={title here},
        ylabel={workshift occupation (in \%)},
        symbolic x coords={Day shift, Weekend shift},
        xtick=data,
        x=0.2\textwidth,
        bar width=0.1\textwidth,
        enlarge x limits=0.5,
        legend style={
            anchor=north,
            at={(0.5,-0.1)},
            legend columns=-1}]
        \addplot coordinates
        {(Day shift,60) (Weekend shift,30)};
        \addplot coordinates
        {(Day shift,30) (Weekend shift,65)};
        \addplot coordinates
        {(Day shift,10) (Weekend shift,5)};
        \legend{task1, task2, task3}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you looked at the `standalone` class?

Comment: you can just add `\pagestyle{empty}` to your document to remove the page counter and then run `pdfcrop filename.pdf` in a command line window. For pdfcrop to work in windows, you need to have a perl interpreter installed. You could also use the externalization function from tikz/pgf. This would require to compile with `shell-escape`

Comment: Standalone is the correct answer! Thanks. Place it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: `preview` is also the correct answer. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `standalone` document class for this.

Note that the `standalone` bundle offers a lot more than just cropping (as detailed in the documentation). In particular, rather than including a cropped `pdf` in your file, you can `\input` the `standalone` file into the `mainfile` using (in your example)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   % need to load all packages needed by sub-files
\usepackage{standalone} % load as a package in the main file

\begin{document}

\input{myfigurefile}

\end{document}
```

This will strip away the preamble from `myfigurefile.tex` and include just the code between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you always compose each TikZ/PSTricks diagram (or whatever) in a separate, compilable (La)TeX input file and compile it to produce a PDF, then using [preview](http://ctan.org/pkg/preview) is enough and simple!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=2pt
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        title={title here},
        ylabel={workshift occupation (in \%)},
        symbolic x coords={Day shift, Weekend shift},
        xtick=data,
        x=0.2\textwidth,
        bar width=0.1\textwidth,
        enlarge x limits=0.5,
        legend style={
            anchor=north,
            at={(0.5,-0.1)},
            legend columns=-1}]
        \addplot coordinates
        {(Day shift,60) (Weekend shift,30)};
        \addplot coordinates
        {(Day shift,30) (Weekend shift,65)};
        \addplot coordinates
        {(Day shift,10) (Weekend shift,5)};
        \legend{task1, task2, task3}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't think typing 3 lines below

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=2pt
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

will waste much time.